# Skipping erroe after update from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS on my dell computer

Tags: 22.04, dell

After update to 22.04 whenever I try to update by terminal i see this :

```
alireza@OptiPlex-5090:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                        
Hit:4 http://oem.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease                         
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/flatpak/stable/ubuntu focal InRelease           
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Hit:7 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                        
Hit:8 http://oem.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                         
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                 
Hit:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease              
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                
Hit:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease              
Hit:14 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/somerville-dla-team/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease              
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease    
Hit:17 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease
Hit:18 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'somerville-cubone-rkl/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com jammy InRelease' doesn't have the component 'somerville-cubone-rkl' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Please let me know to how to fix it

Comment: It seems like "somerville-cubone-rkl"  for jammy(22.04) has not been added to the repositories yet (you can browse `http://dell.archive.canonical.com` on your browser and discover all the files). Did you add those on 20.04 manually, or was it there from the factory? (Dell sells Ubuntu installed laptops, is this one of them?)

Comment: From factory ... I will do according to your recommend

Comment: You already messed with'from factory' and did an update from 20.04 to 22.04, now you have to fix the repositories as Emre suggests.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to install the missing package ?